# SQL Query Join Multipart identifier

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, inner-join

I have these tables, about a car rental firm

[image]

I am trying to get the list of customer who haven't paid for the rental, the ones that are no in the payment table.

This is the record

[image]

This is the query I am trying to use

```
select
   Customer.CustNo, 
   name as name, address as address,
   dbo.Car.VehNo as Vehno, 
   dbo.car.model as model,
   dbo.car.condition as 'Before Condition', 
   dbo.car.[Date Registered] as 'Date Registered', 
   dbo.Car.rentalCost as 'rentalCost',
   dbo.Car.brand as brand, 
   dbo.Rental.[Date Reneted] as 'Date Rented', 
   dbo.Rental.[Date Returned] as 'Date Returned',
   dbo.Rental.condition as 'After Condition'
from 
   Customer, Car  
inner join 
   Rental on Customer.CustNo = Rental.CustNo
where 
   dbo.Payment.rentalNo <> dbo.Rental.rentalNo;
```

But I am getting an error

> Multi-part identifier could not be bound

at

```
Customer.CustNo
```

and

```
dbo.Payment.rentalNo
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should **most definitely** not **MIX** the two styles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    cu.CustNo, cu.name, cu.address,
    ca.VehNo, ca.model,
    ca.condition as 'Before Condition', 
    ca.[Date Registered] as 'Date Registered', 
    ca.rentalCost as 'rentalCost',
    ca.brand, 
    r.[Date Reneted] as 'Date Rented', 
    r.[Date Returned] as 'Date Returned',
    r.condition as 'After Condition'
from Customer cu
inner join Rental r on cu.CustNo = r.CustNo
inner join Car ca on ca.VehNo = r.VehNo
where r.rentalNo not in (select distinct rentalno from payment)
```

The left join method will work too, but using IN might provide slightly better performance.

EDIT: added a brief explanation.

First you chose what columns you want (the SELECT part), the specify how they are related to each other (the INNER JOINs) and finally you specify that you want all rows for which the RentalNo isn't also present in the Payments table (meaning rows that lack payments - the `NOT IN`clause).

The use of column aliases is optional, they just serve to make the query shorter (and possibly easier to read). The query might just as well have been stated like:

```
select
    Customer.CustNo, name, address,
    Car.VehNo, model,
    Car.condition as 'Before Condition', 
    [Date Registered] as 'Date Registered', 
    rentalCost,
    brand, 
    [Date Reneted] as 'Date Rented', 
    [Date Returned] as 'Date Returned',
    Rental.condition as 'After Condition'
from Customer
inner join Rental  on customer.CustNo = rental.CustNo
inner join Car on car.VehNo = rental.VehNo
where Rental.rentalNo not in (select distinct rentalno from payment)
```

The only time you need to specify *Table.Column* is when a column exists with the same name in multiple tables in the query - you then have to qualify from which table you want the data. Also, the use of *as 'New Column Name'* is only needed when you want to change the name/heading of the column displayed, using `name as name`is pointless.

Comment: WOW! this somehow worked , but I am still lost on how this actually worked. If possible please explain in brief tks!

Comment: @JackyBoi I updated my answer with an attempt to explain it. Hope it helps.

Comment: TKS! now I think I got the grasp of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please. Is relation between Customer and Care is CustNo? If not the join needs to be modified accordingly.

```
SELECT   cst.CustNo,
         NAME                  AS NAME,
         ADDRESS               AS ADDRESS,
         cr.VehNo              AS Vehno,
         cr.model              AS model,
         cr.condition          AS 'Before Condition',
         cr.[Date Registered]  AS 'Date Registered',
         cr.rentalCost         AS 'rentalCost',
         cr.brand              AS brand,
         rnt.[Date Reneted]    AS 'Date Rented',
         rnt.[Date Returned]   AS 'Date Returned',
         rnt.condition         AS 'After Condition'
FROM     Customer cst
INNER JOIN   Rental rnt
    ON   cst.CustNo = rnt.CustNo
INNER JOIN   Car cr
    ON   cr.VehNo = rnt.VehNo
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Payments pts
    ON   pts.RentalNo = rnt.RentalNo
WHERE    pts.RentalNo IS NULL;
```

Comment: The last line should reference RentalNo in the payments table, not the rental table, otherwise you won't get the correct results.